# Is there any way to know the size of L1, L2, L3 cache and RAM in Linux?

Tags: hardware, ram

Is there any way to know the size of L1, L2, L3 caches and RAM in Linux?

Comment: Cross-posted on: https://superuser.com/q/837970

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have `lshw` installed:

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
...
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: Internal L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: asynchronous internal write-through data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: Internal L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: burst internal write-through unified
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: Internal L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: burst internal write-back
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1334 MHz (0.7 ns)
          product: M471B5273CH0-CH9
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 67010644
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1334MHz (0.7ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1334 MHz (0.7 ns)
          product: 16JTF51264HZ-1G4H1
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 1
          serial: 3749C127
          slot: DIMM 2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1334MHz (0.7ns)
```

Comment: Please include substance to answers. Don't just mention names of commands, but show their output.

Comment: `lshw` (ran with root permission of course)  didn't give me cache information. but `lscpu` and `dmidecode` tools gave me the results.

Answer (score 28):

#### lscpu

If you care only about the sizes, try `lscpu` from `util-linux`.

#### Example

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               1199.000
BogoMIPS:              5319.88
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

#### x86info

There should be also package/command called x86info.  Assuming you have i386/x86_64, `x86info -c` should provide more detailed information about caches.

#### Example

```
$ x86info -c
x86info v1.30.  Dave Jones 2001-2011
Feedback to <davej@redhat.com>.

Found 4 identical CPUs
Extended Family: 0 Extended Model: 2 Family: 6 Model: 37 Stepping: 5
Type: 0 (Original OEM)
CPU Model (x86info's best guess): Core i7 (Nehalem) [Clarkdale/Arrandale]
Processor name string (BIOS programmed): Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz

Cache info
 L1 Instruction cache: 32KB, 4-way associative. 64 byte line size.
 L1 Data cache: 32KB, 8-way associative. 64 byte line size.
 L2 (MLC): 256KB, 8-way associative. 64 byte line size.
TLB info
 Instruction TLB: 2MB or 4MB pages, fully associative, 7 entries
 Instruction TLB: 4K pages, 4-way associative, 64 entries.
 Data TLB: 4KB or 4MB pages, fully associative, 32 entries.
 Data TLB: 4KB pages, 4-way associative, 64 entries
 Data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way associative, 512 entries.
 Data TLB: 4KB or 4MB pages, fully associative, 32 entries.
 Data TLB: 4KB pages, 4-way associative, 64 entries
 64 byte prefetching.
 Data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way associative, 512 entries.
Found unknown cache descriptors: dd 
Total processor threads: 4
This system has 1 dual-core processor with hyper-threading (2 threads per core) running at an estimated 2.65GHz
```

Comment: Does this include the RAM?

Comment: `x86info` is not installed by default on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 16):

**`getconf`**

```
getconf -a | grep CACHE
```

gives:

```
LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_ICACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL1_DCACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_DCACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE                  262144
LEVEL2_CACHE_ASSOC                 8
LEVEL2_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE                  20971520
LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC                 20
LEVEL3_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL4_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL4_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL4_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
```

Or for a single level:

```
getconf LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE
```

The cool thing about this interface is that it is just a wrapper around the POSIX `sysconf` C function (cache arguments are non-POSIX extensions), and so it can be used from C code as well:

```
long l2 = sysconf(_SC_LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE);
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

**x86 CPUID instruction**

The CPUID x86 instruction also offers cache information, and can be directly accessed by userland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

glibc seems to use that method for x86. I haven't confirmed by step debugging / instruction tracing, but the source for 2.28 [`sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c;h=b9444ddd52051e05183463340f4dd3cf3e61f4dc;hb=3c03baca37fdcb52c3881e653ca392bba7a99c2b#l281) does that:

```
__cpuid (2, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
```

TODO create a minimal C example, lazy now, asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86

ARM also has an architecture-defined mechanism to find cache sizes through registers such as the Cache Size ID Register (CCSIDR), see the [ARMv8 Programmers' Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/den0024/a/DEN0024A_v8_architecture_PG.pdf) 11.6 "Cache discovery" for an overview.

**Memory size**

A few methods:

```
free
cat /proc/meminfo
sysinfo()
```

bibliography:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348007/how-can-i-find-out-the-total-physical-memory-ram-of-my-linux-box-suitable-to-b
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/898941/how-to-check-ram-size/898942
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349889/how-do-you-determine-the-amount-of-linux-system-ram-in-c

Answer (score 4):

You could try this command.

```
$sudo dmidecode -t cache
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t cache | grep -iE "leve|installed"
    Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 1
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Installed SRAM Type: Asynchronous
    Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 2
    Installed Size: 256 kB
    Installed SRAM Type: Burst
    Configuration: Enabled, Socketed, Level 3
    Installed Size: 3072 kB
    Installed SRAM Type: Burst
```

To see RAM simply add the additional switch `-t memory`.

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t cache -t memory
```

#### References

- [finding L2 cache size in Linux](https://superuser.com/a/55777/252686)

Answer (score 4):

There are special files exported to /sys `sysfs` Linux filesystem since 2008:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu

```
What:       /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cache/index*/<set_of_attributes_mentioned_below>
Date:       July 2014(documented, existed before August 2008)
Description:    Parameters for the CPU cache attributes

    allocation_policy:
        - WriteAllocate: allocate a memory location to a cache line
                 on a cache miss because of a write
        - ReadAllocate: allocate a memory location to a cache line
                on a cache miss because of a read
        - ReadWriteAllocate: both writeallocate and readallocate

    coherency_line_size: the minimum amount of data in bytes that gets
                 transferred from memory to cache

    level: the cache hierarchy in the multi-level cache configuration

    number_of_sets: total number of sets in the cache, a set is a
            collection of cache lines with the same cache index

    physical_line_partition: number of physical cache line per cache tag

    shared_cpu_list: the list of logical cpus sharing the cache

    shared_cpu_map: logical cpu mask containing the list of cpus sharing
            the cache

    size: the total cache size in kB

    type:
        - Instruction: cache that only holds instructions
        - Data: cache that only caches data
        - Unified: cache that holds both data and instructions

    ways_of_associativity: degree of freedom in placing a particular block
                of memory in the cache

    write_policy:
        - WriteThrough: data is written to both the cache line
                and to the block in the lower-level memory
        - WriteBack: data is written only to the cache line and
                 the modified cache line is written to main
                 memory only when it is replaced
```

ID files:

```
What:       /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cache/index*/id
Date:       September 2016
Contact:    Linux kernel mailing list <linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org>
Description:    Cache id

    The id provides a unique number for a specific instance of
    a cache of a particular type. E.g. there may be a level
    3 unified cache on each socket in a server and we may
    assign them ids 0, 1, 2, ...

    Note that id value can be non-contiguous. E.g. level 1
    caches typically exist per core, but there may not be a
    power of two cores on a socket, so these caches may be
    numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, ...
```

Comment: I wonder why on my machine `index0` and `index1` both do `level` `1` on kernel v4.15, it is confusing. 0-index preventive coding? :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli华涌低端人口六四事件法轮功, (with the name to not pronounce), probably index0 is about L1 with `type` Data (L1 data cache) and index1 is about L1 with `type` Instruction (L1 instruction cache). Then index2 is of `type` [Unified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Separate_versus_unified) and `level` of 2 (L2 cache, can store both data and instruction)

Comment: ah, yes! I should be more patient to read docs :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### cpuid

Another option is [cpuid](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html) program. It uses `CPUID` instructions and does not require root. It also can work throught `cpuid` Linux kernel module.

```
cache and TLB information (2):
   0x59: data TLB: 4K pages, 16 entries
   0xba: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
   0x4f: instruction TLB: 4K pages, 32 entries
   0xc0: data TLB: 4K & 4M pages, 4-way, 8 entries
   0x80: L2 cache: 512K, 8-way, 64 byte lines
   0x30: L1 cache: 32K, 8-way, 64 byte lines
   0x0e: L1 data cache: 24K, 6-way, 64 byte lines
```

Note that on common consumer CPUs L1 and L2 caches are per core, while L3 cache is shared by all cores.

Comment: `cpuid` is not installed by default on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the L3 then `grep "cache size" < /proc/cpuinfo` should be enough.

However since the way L3 cache is shared among cpu archs differs, its value might need normalization

Comment: Perhaps you want to remove a useless use of cat.